# XmlSerializer. Deserializion of empty Date and Time elements

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to deserialize an Xml file content into a specific object. Everything runs fine but when I include **empty** tag of type date or time in my xml(having xsd that describes my xml structure) the deserialization fails. What can I do to make deserialization working when empty date tags are appear?

Thanks
Pan

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` cannot be empty - instead try using the `DateTime.Min` value.

Comment: It's not up to me. It's a case, I get the msg and I am trying to deserialize.I cannot prevent it